Wavesurfer/react does not work in production
I am using @wavesurfer/react to display waveform in my website.
The waveforms work fine during localhost, but in production the canvas itself does not render.
Here is the code:
       <WavesurferPlayer
        height={35}
        waveColor="white"
        barWidth={2}
        onTimeupdate={(currentTime) => { setCurrentTime(currentTime.getCurrentTime()) }}
        fillParent

        barRadius={20}
        normalize
        progressColor="#7656FF"
        cursorColor='transparent'
        url={beat.preview_url}
        onReady={onReady}
        onFinish={onFinish}
      />

Here is the html rendered in localhost:

Here is the html rendered in production:

As you can see, the canvas itself does not render and shows blank.
